# Issue with clear() and insertHTML with Word Office JS

Tags: javascript, office-js

I'm seeing a strange issue on Word 2016 for Windows.

1) I have two Content Controls, one containing text and one empty:

Some Text
*Click or tap here to enter text*

2) Click on the second content control (the one with the placeholder text) to set input focus

3) Execute a code snippet similar to this:

```
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
        var contentControls = context.document.contentControls;

        context.load(contentControls);

        await context.sync();

        contentControls.items[0].clear();
        contentControls.items[1].insertHtml('<b>Bold</b><i>Italic</i>', 'replace');

        await context.sync();
    });
```

The result looks like this:

[image: Actual result]

If I skip step 2 and don't put the focus on the content control, I get the expected result:

[image: Expected result]

[Here's the ScriptLab gist that explains the issue](https://gist.github.com/htryggva/31ee01ff25c6dd0df21394c66f5ed8ff)

Any ideas? Am I using the API incorrectly or is this a bug?

Comment: I can reproduce. The 1st CC is cleared and moved to after the 2nd one. The placeholder text in the 1st one is only partially replaced with the new text. Also, if the line clearing the 1st CC is commented out, things behave normally. So its the combination of clearing the 1st CC and selecting the 2nd that causes this. Also, if there's any content (other than more CCs) between the 1st and 2nd, it is deleted. Also, only happens with insertHtml, not insertText. I will report to the product team.